# Задать главную папку Apache (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, apache

помогите решить данный вопрос:

Есть: сайт с главной папкой site.ru/public/

Необходимо: сделать папку /public/ главной папкой сайта, что бы все адреса были:
site.ru/page/

В данный момент: site.ru/public/page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В корень сайта файл htaccess:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /public/$1
   ```
2. В папку public  файл htaccess:

   ```
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php
   ```